# Vlookup for different cells location

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do `Vlookup` for target data in different rows.
But unfortunately, I can't find the way to do it.
`Vlookup`, `Hlookup` can't get the target data correctly.

Can you advise?

Resource Data Sheet

[image]

Result Output (expectation)

[image]

Matching ID number consist of these target data.

```
Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim D As String
Dim E As String
Dim F As String

A = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("G1"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("A11"), iSheet.Range("A3:A5"), 0))
B = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("I1"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("A11"), iSheet.Range("A3:A5"), 0))
C = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("K1"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("A11"), iSheet.Range("A3:A5"), 0))

'*** Error Thrown On Next Line (unable to get the index property of the worksheetfunction class)
D = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("G1"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("A12"), iSheet.Range("A3:A5"), 0)) 
E = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("I1"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("A12"), iSheet.Range("A3:A5"), 0))
F = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(iSheet.Range("K1"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSheet.Range("A12"), iSheet.Range("A3:A5"), 0))

iSheet.Range("C7").Value = A & ", " & B & ", " & C
iSheet.Range("C8").Value = D & ", " & E & ", " & F
```

Comment: Your id's aren't the same, so you'd need to match the target format before trying to do a lookup.  It's not clear from your screenshots where your formulas are though.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. i was stuck at how to copy the name into the same cell? matching with same ID number and copy name and paste in selected cell. I have solved the Ref No. with concatenate

Comment: I'm not sure which is the source sheet?  Maybe provide a step-by-step for one lookup so we can follow what needs to be done.

Comment: 1) Target ID number new sheet is matching with Range(A) in Resource data sheet.                                                                                                            2) If is ID number matched then copy Ref no & name (Power, MB, ANT) to the new sheet (as shown in Result output image).

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong track with `VLookup()` and `HLookup()`.
Try using this: (on multiple lines for readability purposes)

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",
          TRUE,
          IF(NOT(ISBLANK(I3)),"POWER", ""),
          IF(NOT(ISBLANK(K3)),"MB", ""),
          IF(NOT(ISBLANK(M3)),"ANT", "")
         )
```

Let me explain:

- `TextJoin()` concatenates information, based on:

  - `","` : the delimiter to be used
  - `TRUE`: how to handle empty cells
  - the arguments to be concatenated
- `IF(NOT(ISBLANK(I3)),"POWER", "")`: if `I3` is filled in, you need to put the word "POWER". If not, put an empty string.

Are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Right... so, this will technically do what you have asked for. But I suspect that it may not be exactly what you actually want. I am afraid your original question was quite unclear and I have had to make some guesses/assumptions.

[image]

```
=CONCAT(
    IF(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",$G$1 & ", ",""),
    IF(INDEX($J$3:$J$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",$I$1 & ", ",""),
    IF(INDEX($L$3:$L$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",$K$1 & ", ","")
)
```

The `CONCAT` function just adds strings together, one after the other.
Within it, we have one formula for each of your merged column headers.

*Please note: If you have lots of column headers, this probably won't be a viable solution. However, making a formula to handle a dynamic number of headers would be far more complex and I would advise re-organising your data to allow use of a simpler formula instead.*

So, the inner formula:

```
IF(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",$G$1 & ", ",""),
```

Similar to how `VLOOKUP` would, the `INDEX`/`MATCH` is returning the POWER reference number for the specific ID Num. If there is no Ref No., it returns an empty string. If there is a Ref No., this is returned along with a trailing comma and space.

This is repeated for each of your Ref columns, and then `CONCAT` sticks all the results together. This does leave a trailing comma, however, that is relatively simple to remove if required, and I will leave that for you to work out.

As for returning the Ref No.'s themselves this can be done in the same way, but instead of returning the header, you repeat the `INDEX`/`MATCH` formula:

[image]

```
=CONCAT(
    IF(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0)) & ", ",""),
    IF(INDEX($J$3:$J$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",INDEX($J$3:$J$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0)) & ", ",""),
    IF(INDEX($L$3:$L$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0))<>"",INDEX($L$3:$L$5,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$5,0)) & ", ","")
)
```

**Why Not `VLOOKUP`?**
You may wonder why I used an `INDEX`/`MATCH` formula, rather than a `VLOOKUP` formula.
`VLOOKUP` would work, however, `INDEX`/`MATCH` is better in literally every way. To my knowledge, there is NEVER a situation where `VLOOKUP` would be a better option.

- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is faster. When you have hundreds or thousands of formulas, you can often speed up a workbook drastically simply by swapping out all of the `VLOOKUP`s.
- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is more versatile. It can work on rows or columns and your lookup range can be anywhere. You can even lookup a value in a 2D table using `INDEX`/`MATCH`/`MATCH`.
- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is more stable. Moving or re-ordering columns doesn't break your formulas.
- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is easier to use. It may look confusing if you are used to `VLOOKUP`, but once you understand it, it is actually easier to use because you can directly reference the ranges, rather than counting the number of columns accross.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying to compile in macro syntax but unfortunately i found error unable to get the index property of the worksheetfunction class in D= Application....... (Syntax shown as above). How to correct this? Can you kindly show me the way?

Comment: @Giftfre Your original question didn't mention VBA at all. You shouldn't really make significant changes to a question like that as it invalidates the answers you already have. I am not sure why it would error on that line in particular when the formula for A is almost identical. What is different about your data in A12 vs A11? Is it not finding a match and returning an error? Id also recommend using `Application.Index`, rather than the `WorkSheetFunction` version, as it has better error handling.